# Hago una query en una base de datos sqlite con Flask Python y me devuelve none cuando hay rows para leer

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlite3

Les dejo el código

```
@app.route("/")
def getInicio():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('datala.db')

    c = conn.cursor()

    row=c.execute('''SELECT * FROM servicio''')

    resultado =c.fetchone()

    print(resultado)


    conn.close()

    return "hola"
```

Comment: para que son las 3 comillas de la string del SELECT? no debeías poner simplemente "SELECT * FROM servicio"?

Comment: Las tres comillas del select son por si lo querés hacer en varios renglones, es indiferente, si lo hago con comillas simple tambien devuelve none

Comment: ¿Ese código te da algún error?, ¿qué muestra el `print`?

Answer (score 0):

Probé tu código (lo modifiqué ligeramente) con una tabla de dos columnas:

```
import sqlite3

def getInicio():
    conn=sqlite3.connect("baseTabla.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    row=c.execute("SELECT * FROM tabla")
    resultado =c.fetchall()
    for res in resultado:
      print(res)
    conn.close()

getInicio()
```

Y funciona sin problemas. Podrías revisar que los datos realmente se encuentren en el archivo.

Comment: Gracias por tu preocupación!!! empezó a funcionar después de esas modificaciones!!!